# Display Child Product SKU in Product Page

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, sku

I am using Magento 2. I would like to display child product SKU in Main product page while user clicks on configurable Swatches.

I am trying to gather information from below file.

```
public_html\vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\frontend\templates\product\view\renderer.phtml
```

like below

```
<div class="swatch-opt"></div>
<script>
    require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "swatchRenderer"], function ($) {
        $('.swatch-opt').SwatchRenderer({
            jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'

        });
    });

    console.log('<?php echo $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>');
</script>
```

I am getting below output in **console**.

```
{"90":{"12":{"type":"1","value":"#474747","label":"Black"},"13":{"type":"1","value":"#45bcf8","label":"Blue"},"20":{"type":"1","value":"#da859c","label":"Pink"},"21":{"type":"1","value":"#a15ebb","label":"Purple"},"22":{"type":"1","value":"#cb5d4a","label":"Red"}}}
```

But I could not find **SKU** there. I would like to get **SKU** to display that in Main product Page.

Answer (score 0):

If you use version 2.1.9 and below.
open file **vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Data.php**
find **private function getAllSizeImages(ModelProduct $product, $imageFile)**
add:

> 'sku' => $product->getSku()

all function code looke like:

```
private function getAllSizeImages(ModelProduct $product, $imageFile) {
return [
 'large' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large')
     ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
     ->setImageFile($imageFile)
     ->getUrl(),
 'medium' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')
     ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)
     ->setImageFile($imageFile)
     ->getUrl(),
 'small' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
     ->setImageFile($imageFile)
     ->getUrl(),
     'sku' => $product->getSku(),
 ];}
```

well be callback SKU.

more information: https://forum.magentochina.org/t/sku/33

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, when choosing options, e.g. the *images* and the *price* will change, but **not SKU.**

In order to display the SKU of the selected product, you can create a [Plugin (Interceptor)](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html%5D) for `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable::getJsonConfig()` where you need to add missing `SKU` for each simple product.

Switching `SKU` when selecting an option can be implemented in `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/base/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` and `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/web/js/configurable.js` depending on the [type of attribute](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html#product-variation-attribute-requirements).

---

I made free `VCT Change SKU Dynamically` module that solve this problem.